# server can't receive eof in java

Tags: java

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
while ((readBytes = is.read()) != -1)
{
    fos.write(readBytes);
    System.err.println(readBytes);
}
System.err.println(readBytes);
clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
fos.close();
System.out.println("Trans complete");
```

client sends -1, but server can't receive -1

**how can I get all file**?

Comment: How do you know client sends -1?

Comment: A client doesn't *send* -1; the only way to "transmit" an EOF is to close the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Call flush() before closing the FileOutputStream.